# Accept JSON array as input in POST Node API - Express

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

It should be fairly easy question,
I have been doing following on server side-

```
exports.findByItemIds = function(req, res) {
    var id = req.body;
    var idsProjects  = id['items'];
    console.log(idsProjects);
    db.collection(collection, function(err, collection) {

        if (err) {
            throw err;
            console.log("error");
        } else {
            collection.find({'item_id': {$in:idsProjects}}).toArray(function(err, item){                  
                res.send(item);
            });
        }
    });
};
```

and I am sending

```
POST /itemsbyids HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:3000
Content-Type: application/json
Cache-Control: no-cache
Postman-Token: 440972dc-e534-051f-a2a5-5bdaaf2da73a
{"items":["1243","948"]}
```

using `console.log(idsProjects)` I am able to print

```
["1243","948"]
```

Now how I can pass it as an array at $in:idsProjects to call `MongoDb` query?

Right now it gives me 
`Unexpected token, at Object.Parse(native)`  error

## Solution

What I learned that my MongoDb's field `item_id` is integer type, hence when I was passing an array like `["323","54234"]`, it was not giving me any results.

While, passing `[323,54234]` as input gave me results.
My snippet to accept JSON array was all fine.

Comment: what is your node and express version? It works fine for me with node 6.5 and express 4.

Comment: my node version is 4.5.0 and express is 3.21.2. The problem I am facing is, that it is not fetching data from Mongo, while it was working fine when I was passing data as form data rather that `application/json`

Comment: That invalid HTTP request is too distracting. I can't focus on the question.

Comment: Is it a wrong HTTP request? (this is my first API written, so don't know much about it)

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible that the console.log output is sort of deceptive and idsProject is not actually an array?  Maybe try outputting with `inspect`.  Also, just to check, are you sure that they are supposed to be string containing numbers rather than just numbers in the array?